# Bash functions executing when defined at the top of the document?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script and adding functions to make things easy(borrowing from LUA) but when I execute the script the functions at the top get executed before even being called, Is this expected? If so how can I not have this happen?

Here is my script: http://pastebin.com/GDRzSHk6 
And the output: http://pastebin.com/kQDbHpq8

Note that it is not finished yet. Its suppose to be a compile script that asks the user some things then gets to build the source.

Comment: +1 to nullify the downvote. This is valid question. Besides, the downvoter did not bother to justify the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: `function() debianDeps{........}`

You should make it just `debianDeps(){........}` OR `function debianDeps (){........}`

Comment: It still does not work after doing debianDeps(){...}. Its still executing everything.

Comment: I copied your code upto line 41 and ran it on my ubuntu. It is working fine. There is no output as this code only defines the function upto line 41. What is the error/message you get when you run this code. The code at pastebin upto line 41 is good.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of bad syntax for declaring your syntax:

You have this:

```
function() debianDeps {
apt-get install git cmake build-essential liblua5.2-dev libgmp3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libboost-system-dev }
```

It should be like this:

```
debianDeps() {
    apt-get install git cmake build-essential liblua5.2-dev libgmp3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libboost-system-dev
}
```

Comment: Or actually drop the `function` keyword altogether, it's just a bad non-POSIX habit.

Comment: I assume you mean POSIX when you say bourne shell. The standard only specifies the `name ()` form; use of the `function` keyword (with which makes the `()` is optional) is a `bash` extension.

Comment: Yes I meant POSIX only.